# how could add javascript to a pdf for showing an alert when it open?

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, acrobat

i want add a javasript alert code to my pdf for showing some alert when i open it ...
how could i do that?
i found some paper and ebook like
http://www.pdfill.com/download/AcroJS.pdf
and
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/javascript/AcroJSGuide.pdf
they explain it very dificult and complicated but my goal is very simple and actually i think it is not really necessary to know all of it's detail
and i must mention that i develop a program for  adobe acrobat reader in android
tnx for helping

Comment: How are you generating the PDFs?

Comment: with Adobe Acrobat X Professional 10.1.4 ... What is your offer?what is good for my goal?
thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is in this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380293/Javascript-in-PDF)

we could create a pdf in c# like this:

```
using BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf;

namespace JavascriptInPdf
{
public static class Demo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

    pdf.OnOpenDocument =pdf.CreateJavaScriptAction("app.alert(\"Hello    CodeProject!\", 3);");

        pdf.Save("Hello world.pdf");
    }
}
  }
```